# Not able to get form-data sent from angular to node server

Tags: angularjs, node.js, multer

I am sending `form-data` along with `image-data`. 
But I am unable to get data on the node server when sent inside `FormData`.
I could see data on the `angular` controller on `console.log`.

*angular code*:

```
$scope.saveInfo = function(){
  var formData = new FormData;
  console.log('Update function');
  for(key in $scope.seller){
    formData.append(key, $scope.seller[key]);
  }
  console.log(key, $scope.seller);
  var file = $('#file')[0].files[0];
  formData.append('image', file);

  $http.put('/api/seller/businessInformation', formData, {
    transformRequest: angular.Identity,
    headers: {
      'Content-type': undefined
    }
  }).then(function(res){

  });
}
```

*Node.Js:*
I could see image data on `console.log(req.files);`, 
but `console.log(req.body);` prints [object object].

Answer (score -4, accepted):

The problem is with the ng-model data binding.
I was binding data like this: 'seller.a.b.c' 
Instead I did `seller.a` and it worked.

Comment: This answer is totally irrelevant to the question you posted

Answer (score 5):

The best way to tackle this issue is

(i) `JSON.stirngify(req.body)` in your code.

(ii) See what is the data getting printed, then based on the output you can use req.body.whateverField

**EDIT**

You can access FormData as,

```
console.log(req.files.file.name);
```

and to access FormData you can use

```
var a = JSON.parse(req.body.name);
console.log(a);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I did that and got nothing. On `for(key in $scope.seller){
   console.log(key)
  }`, I could see only `businessInformation`.

Comment: Code, i have posted in the question, there is nothing wrong with API, If I hit API with POSTMAN, then I am able to update my collection. The problem is when I am trying to append form-data with image, then i can see image data on the server not the fprm-data.

Comment: I am using Google Chrome

Comment: Umm, see I am able to get image-data on the server side, because on doing `console.log(req.files)`, I could see image data. But the problem is with other form-data, that contains text-fields and dropdowns, all those data are coming as undefined, because angular is not sending those fields

Comment: If you take a close look at my angular code, on execution of `for(key in $scope.seller){ console.log(key) }`, i should get all the keys, but iam getting only `businessInformation`

Comment: hope you understood my problem

Comment: yes thats what i am saying it works for me. check this code https://gist.github.com/sajeetharan/cf4bde44a5aa4da42721e2b9cb7a42dd

Answer (score 0):

`req.body` is an object. If your form-data contains name and age. then you can get those values in node like below

```
req.body.name
req.body.age
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My model contains data like this: `info.name.firstname`. I tried logging that data, and I am getting `undefined`.

Comment: can you tell what will be logged in the line console.log(key, $scope.seller);

Comment: printing nothing

Comment: i hope you got the answer, you are not posting anything to node server

Comment: yup, i got the answer